# C++ method overloading

Tags: c++, oop, overloading

I have a method and I need to overload it, but as I try I get error which says `no matching function for call to Vehicle_Renting::Order::Order()`

Here's how it looks:

Class declaration:

```
class Order
{
    private:
    class ImplementationOrder;
    ImplementationOrder* implOrder;
```

Inner class:

```
class Order::ImplementationOrder
{
private:
    string date;
    int price, id;
    friend class Order;
    bool isVerified;
    vector<Vehicle> orderedVehicles;
    Customer* customer;
    friend class Order;
};
```

Constructors:

```
Order::Order(int price)
        :implOrder(new ImplementationOrder())
    {
        #ifdef DEBUG
            clog << DEBUG_PREFIX "Constructor (1 arg) called!" << endl;
        #endif // DEBUG
        setDate();
        setPrice(price);
        assert(price >= 0);
    }

    // copy constructor---------------------------------------------------------
    Order::Order(const Order &other)
      : implOrder(new ImplementationOrder(*(other.implOrder)))
    {
    }
```

Methods:

```
void addOrder(const Order& o, const Client& c);
void addOrder(const Client& c);
void Auto_Rent::addOrder(const Order& o, const Customer& c)
{
    addCustomer(c);
    int pos = getCustomerPosition(c);
    Order o1(o);
    o1.setCustomer(implAuto_Rent->customers[pos]);
    implAuto_Rent->orders.push_back(o1);
}

void Auto_Rent::addOrder(const Customer& c)
{
    addCustomer(c);
    int pos = getCustomerPosition(c);
    Order o1;
    o1.setCustomer(implAuto_Rent->customers[pos]);
    implAuto_Rent->orders.push_back(o1);
}
```

I create object called customer:

```
Customer c5("Agriosas", "Lasiokas", 1994), c6("Edves", "Lasas", 1992), c7("MAtkes", "brolis", 1991);
```

And I call addOrder function:

```
  s.addOrder(c5);
  s.addOrder(c7);
  s.addOrder(c6);
```

Comment: Where is code where you have called these functions?

Comment: Show the class declaration of `Order` please. That's the code in question at least! Most probably you simply don't have a default constructor provided for class `Order`.

Comment: Missing the line producing the error, missing the supposed declaration of that ctor, missing its definition. We basically arrive at the same conclusion as the compiler: if you want a working executable, show some source code.

Comment: Your `Order` class has no default-constructor, but somewhere in the code you haven't shown us you're doing something like `Order odr;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
Order o1;
```

You need the default-constructor to construct this `Order` object, please add one to your class that does the right thing.

Comment: How it should look? Sorry for asking I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @user3476593 `Order() : implOrder(...) { ... }`